# Passing character array?

Tags: c++, function

I am having trouble passing my char array to a function. Whenever I try to do so, I get an error displaying the following :

> Error 1 error C2664: 'void Print(char)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [22]' to 'char'

I'm not sure what the issue could be. Some advice would be great.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Print(char);

int main(){
    char arr1[] = { "Hello how are you? / " };
    Print(arr1);
}

void Print(char arr[]){
    for (char i = 0; i != '/'; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Omit the braces: `char arr1[] = "Hello how are you? / " ;` Also declaration `void Print(char);` doesn't match the definition `void Print(char arr[]){`

Comment: Also, **why are you passing a `char[]` in C++?** This situation could be done just as easily and a lot more safely with `std::string`. You can index them just the same with `[i]`, plus you can get the `length()`.

Answer (score 3):

1.Function declaration and definition of `Print` don't match. According to the declaration, `Print` accepts `char` as its argument, that's why compiler complains. Change the declaration to

```
void Print(char[]);
```

2.`for (char i = 0; i != '/'; i++)`, the condition `i != '/'` doesn't check the element of char array, it should be `arr[i] != '/'`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

This program works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Print(char *arr);


int main()
{
char arr1[] = { "Hello how are you? / " };
Print(arr1);

    return 0;
}

void Print(char *arr) {

int i = 0;

while (arr[i] != '/')
{
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
    ++i;
}


}
```

I feel that a while statement is better here than a for statement and you need to use arr as a pointer.

Comment: Why the while loop? A for loop would do the exact same thing, in one line of code that people instantly recognize.

Comment: You are correct; you code is better than mine. Thank you for your input.